# django - save instance - attribute as a variable - not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to write a small function which saves the image field of the instance.

```
def save_image_to_model(instance, **kwargs):
   fieldname = kwargs.pop('fieldname')
   imgpath = kwargs.pop('imgpath')

   imagefile_name = urlparse(imgpath).path.split('/')[-1]
   instance.fieldname.save(imagefile_name,
                        ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(imgpath).read()))
   instance.save()
```

but i am getting

```
'MyModel' object has no attribute 'fieldname'
```

i am calling it like:

```
save_image_to_model(myinstance, fieldname='bg_image', imgpath='http://.../img.png')
```

I thinking about using `getattr(instance, fieldname)` but i am not sure if this is the right way.

how can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**:

i just tried:

```
instance.getattr(instance, fieldname).save(imagefile_name,
                        ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(imgpath).read()))
```

I am getting `'MyModel' object has attribute 'getattr'`

Comment: Please add the model definition and full stacktrace :)

Comment: @doniyor What make you think `getattr` would not be "the right way" ?

Comment: @doniyor no, getattr does *not* take a model as a param. getattr takes an object and returns the relevant attribute. It doesn't care what the object is. That is exactly the right solution in this case.

Comment: `getattr` takes any python object as first param, and in Python everything (well, everything you can bind to a name at least) is an object. You're overcomplexifying simple things, really. And `getattr` is a builtin function, not a method.

Comment: No, why should it? Have you defined a method called `getattr` on your model class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman there is predefined one, do i have to use this? ``def __getattr__(self, item)``.. but i am getting now ``maximum recersion depth exceeded``

Comment: @DanielRoseman i defined the method in my model already. i will update my question

Comment: No, my point is you *don't need one*. Just use `getattr(instance, fieldname)` like you said right at the start.

Comment: @doniyor I repeat: `getattr` is a builtin _function_. All you need is `field = getattr(instance, fieldname)`, then `field.save(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code but it will show you how to use `getattr`

```
def save_image_to_model(instance, **kwargs):
   fieldname = kwargs.pop('fieldname')
   imgpath = kwargs.pop('imgpath')
   imagefile_name = urlparse(imgpath).path.split('/')[-1]
   data = urllib2.urlopen(imgpath).read()
   field = getattr(instance, fieldname)
   field.save(imagefile_name, ContentFile(data))
   instance.save()
```